# jms adapter not getting uploaded to server

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set my local environment using 6.2.0.1-WL-StudioP2-IF201604301301.

I am using default configuration provided except changing context path to /worklight/. There are some adapters created in the project. All the adapters are getting successfully deployed in `worklight console except JMS adapters`.

When I try to deploy jms adapters with `initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory`  it gives error message :

> Adapter deployment
>   failed:>RuntimeException:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/jms/ExceptionListener.  adapter.xml file is configured as
>   follows where url is the path to .binding file. namingConnection
>   initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"
>   password="ChangeM3N0Wx" 
>                 url="file:C:/Code/nx_c2c_live_phase1_delivery/nx_c2c_live/server/conf/mqbinding"
>   user="mqm"/>

Could you please let me know if I am missing any configuration so that jms adapters for this initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"  gets successfully deployed in WL Console.
Any config required in server.xml as getting NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: I have all the jars needed in server\lib directory     CL3Export.jar
    CL3Nonexport.jar
    com.ibm.mq.axis2.jar
    com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
    com.ibm.mq.defaultconfig.jar
    com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
    com.ibm.mq.jar
    com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
    com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi.jar
    com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
    com.ibm.mq.postcard.jar
    com.ibm.mq.soap.jar
    com.ibm.mq.tools.ras.jar
    com.ibm.mqjms.jar
    connector.jar
    dhbcore.jar
    fscontext.jar
    jta.jar
    providerutil.jar
    rmm.jar